# What data structure does this function represent?

Tags: python, binary-tree, b-tree

I have the following function and I'm not really sure if they are implementing a Binary Tree or a B-Tree.

Here is the code:

```
def foo(x):
    if x:
        a, b, c = x
        return foo(a) + b + foo(c)
    else:
        return 0
```

Could anyone help me figuring out which data structures are being used?

Comment: this is a normal method if conditions

Comment: I suggest that you actually read about data structures and their use cases.

Comment: Where did you get this code? Are you following a tutorial or book post?. Binary tree is non-linear data structure. Read more here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binarytree-module-in-python/

Comment: I don't think this is implementing any kind of data structure.  It looks almost like a quick sort of tuples, except it's not doing the sorting part.

Comment: Hi @Aman, it is a quiz in wich I am prompt to identify which is the data structure used with that implementation.

Comment: Post link to it.@Axel G. Aguilar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is *indeed* a binary tree but, to some (usually those more comfortable with pointers), a rather strange implementation. Each node of the tree is a 3-tuple holding:

- the entire left sub-tree as a 3-tuple, or a false-type value if there's no sub-tree;
- the value of this node; and
- the entire right sub-tree 3-tuple or false-type value.

Your `foo` function is actually summing up all the nodes, althoug I'd make a few minor changes:

```
def sum_tree(tpl):
    if tpl:
        return foo(tpl[0]) + tpl[1] + foo(tpl[2])
    return 0

# Construct tree for testing:
#          __42__          (42)
#         /      \
#        7        5        (12)
#       / \      /
#     12   17   3          (32)
#                          ----
#                          (86)

tree = [[[None, 12, [None, 7, None]], 17, None], 42, [[None, 3, None], 5, None]]
print(sum_tree(tree)) # Output is `86`.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response :) @paxdiablo, so you quickly identified that is a binary tree data structure because it is a recursive function, and also in the return statement we have at the left the same function call with index 0 `foo(tpl1[0])`, and then at the middle you identified the root, wich is not calling the function istelf and only has de leaves at left and right `tpl[1]` and finally `foo(tpl[2])` at the right which is calling itself.